# Get path from a JSP with Apache Tiles 3 and Spring MVC 3.2.3

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, tiles-3

I'd like to get the current path of the page I'm on from inside the JSP file.  The JSP file in this case being a Tile as part of the apache tiles framework.

The URL I'm hitting is `http://localhost:8080/dashboard/projects` where 'dashboard' is the servlet and 'projects' maps to a spring controller like so:

```
@RequestMapping( { "/projects" } )
public String showAllProjectsPage( Map< String, Object > model ) {
    return "projects";
}
```

Where "projects" refers to a tile defined in my views.xml like so:

```
<tiles-definitions>
  <definition name="template" template="/WEB-INF/views/template.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/views/shared/header.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="sidebar" value="/WEB-INF/views/shared/sidebar.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/views/shared/footer.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="head" value="/WEB-INF/views/shared/head.jsp" />
  </definition>
  <definition name="home" extends="template">
    <put-attribute name="content" value="/WEB-INF/views/home/home.jsp" />
  </definition>
  <definition name="developer" extends="template">
    <put-attribute name="content" value="/WEB-INF/views/developers/developer.jsp"></put-attribute>
  </definition>
  <definition name="developers" extends="template">
    <put-attribute name="content" value="/WEB-INF/views/developers/developers.jsp"></put-attribute>
  </definition>
  <definition name="project" extends="template">
    <put-attribute name="content" value="/WEB-INF/views/projects/project.jsp"></put-attribute>
  </definition>
  <definition name="projects" extends="template">
    <put-attribute name="content" value="/WEB-INF/views/projects/projects.jsp"></put-attribute>
  </definition>
</tiles-definitions>
```

I've tried the following methods and they aren't working for me:

```
<% out.println(request.getPathInfo(  )); %>
```

Output: "`null`"

```
<% out.println(request.getPathTranslated(  )); %>
```

Output: "`null`"

```
<% out.println(request.getRequestURI(  )); %>
```

Output: "`/dashboard/WEB-INF/views/template.jsp`"

```
<% out.println(request.getRequestURL(  )); %>
```

Output: "`http://localhost:8080/dashboard/WEB-INF/views/template.jsp`"

```
<% out.println(request.getServletPath(  )); %>
```

Output: "`/WEB-INF/views/template.jsp`"

The part of the path I'm interested in is 'projects', and I thought that the method `request.getPathTranslated()` would do that for me, but no dice.  I can only get back 'null' or else the path the the tiles template.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what `getPathTranslated()` is supposed to do, but if it doesn't work can you add the path to the `model` as a workaround?

```
@RequestMapping("/projects")
public String showAllProjectsPage( Map< String, Object > model ) {
    model.put("tileDef", "projects");
    return "projects";
}
```

Then in your JSP access it like so:

```
<span id="tileDef">${tileDef}</span>
```

Comment: This is what I ended up doing, although I'd still like someone to chime in with some insight as to why getPathTranslated() doesn't work.  The javadoc says: "Returns any extra path information after the servlet name but before the query string" which is exactly what I'm looking for.